# `code` command requests root after trust disabled

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Using Ubuntu 20.04

Until recently, I was able to open files in vscode via the terminal with the `code` command. However, after I unchecked `Security > Workspace > Trust: Enabled` in Settings (UI) this feature is broken.

Regardless of workspace trust status, I am met with the following:

```
-$ code
need to run as root or suid
-$ sudo code
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a restart of VSCode did not solve the problem, it went away after a full computer reboot.

Comment: I don't know if it's really the same issue, but I had the same error message displayed for `npm` command and the computer restart truly helped. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
### Try kill any VSCode instance:
for pid in $(ps aux|grep "/code"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}')
do
    kill -9 $pid
done

### Now, reopen the VSCode and try again
```